# encode regex URL using JS

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to encode url using JS with the following for example

```
https://ghghfg.dfsdsfds.com/dfdsfs/fds?t=5411&a=493&cp=Jan+Updated&d=scsdc%20cdcsc%20cdscsd
```

I expect to see a result with an object with params like this

```
"{t: "5411",
a: "493",
cp: "Jan+Updated",
d: "scsdc%20cdcsc%20cdscsd"}"
```

Comment: here is suggestation i got but doesnt work
https://jsfiddle.net/57nzt1sk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest way but some string manipulation does the job

```
JSON.parse('{' + url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&').map(x => "\"" + x.split('=')[0]+ "\" : \"" + x.split('=')[1]+ "\"").join() + '}')
```